# convert column file into matrix with awk

Tags: bash, matrix, awk, data-conversion

I have a single column file. The number of rows is a multiple of 24. The total number of rows is not known a priori.

What I'm trying to do is to use awk to convert the single column into a matrix of size n x 24, where

```
n = number_of_rows/24.
```

I want to use awk because I'm using pipe to send the output of tar to awk since i just need certain columns of the whole file.

myfile.dat contains floats like:

```
23.0
20.0
17.0
16.0
16.0
15.0
18.0
20.0
23.0
25.0
27.0
29.0
30.0
31.0
32.0
31.0
30.0
29.0
27.0
25.0
23.0
22.0
20.0
19.0
23.0
22.0
```

and many more...

```
awk '{ 
 for (r = 1; r <= 72; r++) { 
  for (c = 1; c <= 24; c++) {
   a[r, c] =   $1
  }
 }
}
END {
 for (r = 1; r <= 72; r++) {
  for (c = 1; c <= 24; c++) {
   printf a[r, c]
  }
 }
}' myfile.dat
```

All the above in a sigle line. I am using the number 72 to test because I dont know how to get the total number of lines other than:

```
wc -l myfile.dat
```

The result is a repetition of each entry and not a matrix.

If we consider that each element of the input column is x[1] to x[n*24] The output matrix should be

```
x1  x2  x3  x4  ... x24
x25 x26 x27 x28 ... x48
x49 x50 x51 x52 ... x72
...
...                 xn
```

Does this makes sense? 
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can also use `pr` which allows to specify number of columns required

```
$ seq 72 | pr -24ats' '
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48
49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72
```

If `pr` complains of `page width too narrow`, you need to increase page width from default 72. The formula is `(col-1)*len(delimiter) + col` where `col` is number of columns required

For ex:

```
$ # 99 is minimum width required for 50 columns with single character wide delimiter
$ seq 100 | pr -J -w99 -50ats,
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50
51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100
```

As output delimiter required is space, can also use

```
< input xargs -d'\n' -n24
```

`-d'\n'` so that each line from input file is considered as single argument

Answer (score 2):

With paste and data from stdin:

```
cat file | paste -d " " - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
```

Output:

```
23.0 20.0 17.0 16.0 16.0 15.0 18.0 20.0 23.0 25.0 27.0 29.0 30.0 31.0 32.0 31.0 30.0 29.0 27.0 25.0 23.0 22.0 20.0 19.0
23.0 22.0
```

Comment: thanks a lot, great approach, it saves the trouble of defining the number of rows. How would one do it without typing the dashes? Anyway it is indeed an efficient solution to the question. Many thanks.

Comment: @Arraval you can use `printf` trick... `paste -d' ' $(printf -- '- %.s' {1..24})`

Comment: @Arraval: or with `awk`: `cat file | paste -d " " $(awk -v e=24 'BEGIN{for(i=0;i<e;i++) printf "%s","- "}')` ;)